# HTML / CSS image dimensions set in percentage doesn't display properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design

I'm working on a mobile friendly website & I'm a bit baffled by this issue I currently have with an image attribute.

I have its dimensions set as percentage. It displays fine with IE7+, Firefox & Chrome but not Safari. It distorts the image drastically!

Do I need to use JavaScript in order to display the image properly?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or fiddle or link to the page in question?

Comment: Please provide some relevant code/fiddle/screen shot so at least we can see what problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks guys,

Still in draft:

http://marklaurel.com/uft/000.tmplt.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code in question:

```
<img src="images/uftMap.jpg" border="0" width="95%" height="95%" alt="Universal Fitness &amp; Training on Google maps" name="Universal Fitness &amp; Training on Google maps">
```

Remove the height attribute and the browser will scale it proportionally.

Putting percentages in the height and width attributes is not strictly copacetic though. From the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html)

> height = non-negative integer:
>       The height of the image, in CSS pixels.
>
> width = non-negative integer:
>       The width of the image, in CSS pixels.

If you're set on styling this inline rather than with a style sheet, you'd be better off with a style attribute:

```
<img src="images/uftMap.jpg" border="0" style="max-width: 95%" alt="Universal Fitness &amp; Training on Google maps" name="Universal Fitness &amp; Training on Google maps">
```

Comment: Putting percentages in the height and width attributes is not strictly copacetic though. From the HTML5 spec <- I was unaware of that...I went here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp to double check when Safari wouldn't play nice. I'll use the 'max-width' attribute going forward.

Comment: @Mark Laurel There are much better resources are out there than [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) ;-) Always best to go to the source, [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) If my answer solved your problem, accept it and it will add to my rep and add to your acceptance percentage.

Comment: Dig the w3fools link...admittedly, I didn't click through many of the search results from google- the 1st link I clicked on was the developers section from apple but wasn't much help. So I clicked the 2nd or 3rd that's where I found w3schools. I was puzzled cuz from my understanding Safari IS fully HTML5/css3 compliant. So i thought to ask here to double check my code.